# Set environment variable for all of tmux shells when gnome-sessions gets restarted

Tags: environment-variables, tmux, hook

To solve [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/51132/36831), I need to set the environment variable `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` for all shells inside `tmux` every time I restart gnome without restarting tmux (this is often). How can I best solve this?

- I cannot cleanly [change another processes' environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/205064/974555).
- I cannot [send a command to every pane](https://superuser.com/q/492266/133195)
- I could set the environment variable in my `PROMPT_COMMAND`. It means I need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> before I can run gnome applications. It's ugly and overkill.
- I could set the environment variable by [executing a command before every command](https://superuser.com/q/175799/133195), but that's a bit overkill.

Is there another way to fix this in a cleaner way?

Comment: I think the "executing a command before every command" is perfectly reasonable, in fact. depending on your shell, I was going to suggest something exactly like that until I followed your link and saw it was the bash version of what I was already thinking.  It's not really overkill if it's necessary and does the job. Now, spawning subshells, querying databases, molesting other processes.... that would be overkill. This option (and the PROMPT_COMMAND variation ) are, perhaps, hacky and ugly, but not overkill. Still, much of what's done in shells is a bit hacky so... revel in it.

Comment: Maybe I'm too perfectionist in wanting a *clean* solution.

Comment: There is that. Still, you're trying to modify existing independent, unrelated processes. That's not a particularly clean activity to begin with. I wonder, though, if this solution would still need an extra enter  before working. In zsh, a quick test suggests it seems to. Not sure about bash. THAT would make it unclean :-)

Answer (score 4):

In this specific case, instead of letting Gnome run `dbus-launch` to create a random D-Bus address, start `dbus-daemon` explicitly early in your X session startup and give it a fixed address like `unix:path=~/.dbus-$HOSTNAME-$DISPLAY`.

Given the information in the [bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=582839), you may even be able to get away with `unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` and let applications find out the bus address from the root window properties.

In the general case, your assessment is correct: all you have is unreliable methods such as `ptrace` (which may crash the program, or not work due to a security framework such as Apparmor or SELinux) or injecting a shell command (which only works in panes that are currently at a shell prompt). Running a command at each shell prompt (with zsh's `preexec` or bash's `PROMPT_COMMAND`) at least doesn't risk breaking stuff.

Another solution would be an `LD_PRELOAD` library that intercepts `getenv` calls. This also feels like overkill.

Your best bet is to let the application do the job by creating a level of indirection: arrange for the value of the environment variable to remain valid, and for the application to interpret it in a situation-aware manner. Letting the application look up the D-Bus bus address in the root window properties is an example of this approach.

Comment: Useful, but perhaps this answer fits better with [the other question](http://askubuntu.com/q/51132/36831)?

Comment: @gerrit I fear you won't find anything better. I've added some explanations.

Comment: Does simply setting `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = unix:path=~/.dbus-$HOSTNAME-$DISPLAY` before the command not work? Why not?

Comment: @Oxwivi I don't understand your comment. Before what command? `dbus-daemon` and program using D-Bus need to agree on the address.

Comment: Before command to run program using DBus, for example `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = unix:path=~/.dbus-$HOSTNAME-$DISPLAY sudo gnome-terminal`. I'm trying to integrate an app running in LXC container with Ubuntu's `indicator-appmenu` which doesn't happen automatically because both `sudo` and remote app are on separate bus session.

Comment: My understanding is, I can mount host machine's DBus socket in the container and tell the container app to use that socket, so I'm asking if setting the variable before running the command will work. On the host I tried `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS sudo gnome-terminal`, but the appmenu does not integrate. I can't figure out if setting the variable not work or if it's the wrong approach to integrate appmenu in the first place.

Comment: @Oxwivi `sudo` removes most environment variables, in most configurations. `sudo DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS …` might help. With a container in play, you also need to ensure that the socket is available (at the same location, otherwise you need to use a different value of the environment variable) in the container.

Comment: Ah, I realized it after the last comment, but I've got stuck in two places: I can't find the socket file the variable points to. `unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-zXZ0R4LbkG`, there's nothing like that in `/tmp/` or `~/.dbus/`; and I set the variable after `sudo` for `gnome-terminal`, it says this: `Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: The connection is closed`

Comment: @Oxwivi An abstract socket is not visible in the filesystem, it's only visible via the socket API. I think lxc doesn't virtualize the socket namespace, so it should be visible under the same name inside the container.

Comment: Is there anyway to test that it is visible? If it is visible and the app still doesn't behave as I want it to, I could at least figure out that this isn't the correct approach or something more needs to be done. And hanks for all the help so far.

Comment: @Oxwivi `strace`