# Failed to get bus connection: Could not connect: Connection refused

Tags: tmux, d-bus

When I'm running

`evince file.pdf`

I got this error

`Failed to get bus connection: Could not connect: Connection refused`

`Ubuntu 12.04`

I have to reboot. Can I repair this error without reboot?

Comment: @don_crissti It's on my machine, yes under `tmux`. I have to wait until it begins again and tell you the result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This message indicates that the [D-Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus) daemon has died. You need to restart it. Run `dbus-launch`.

Perhaps the daemon is still running but not responding. If that's the case, kill it, then run `dbus-launch`.

If the environment variable `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` is set, unset it. Most applications (I haven't checked about Evince) can find out the D-Bus address without it.

For more information, see [Set environment variable for all of tmux shells when gnome-sessions gets restarted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67043/set-environment-variable-for-all-of-tmux-shells-when-gnome-sessions-gets-restart/67124#67124)

Comment: I've seen this after launching bad lxc containers. This completely locked the hypervisor. Not even reboot worked then. I had to remove all related exports, kill dbus, init and systemd and then `dbus-launch` followed by `init q`. After this I was able to do a reboot again.