# UDEV executes bash script only partially

Tags: bash, shell-script, arch-linux, keyboard, udev

I have this UDEV rule, which gets activated when I plug in my keyboard:

```
ACTION=="add", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:046A:0011.00??/input/input??/event[0-9][0-9]*", ATTRS{name}=="HID 046a:0011", ATTRS{phys}=="usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0", RUN+="/home/*user*/.udev_rule_scripts/cherry_keyboard.sh", SYMLINK+="cherrysymlink"
```

It should

1. create a symlink `/dev/cherrysymlink`, which it does, and
2. execute a shell script, which it doesn't.

Here's the debugging output of `udevadm test /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:046A:0011.0003/input/input18/event17`:

```
This program is for debugging only, it does not run any program
specified by a RUN key. It may show incorrect results, because
some values may be different, or not available at a simulation run.

.INPUT_CLASS=kbd
ACTION=add
DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-046a_0011-event-kbd /dev/cherrysymlink /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-event-kbd
DEVNAME=/dev/input/event17
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:046A:0011.0003/input/input18/event17
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_KEY=1
ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
ID_MODEL=0011
ID_MODEL_ENC=0011
ID_MODEL_ID=0011
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_1_1_0
ID_REVISION=0100
ID_SERIAL=046a_0011
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=046a
ID_VENDOR_ENC=046a
ID_VENDOR_ID=046a
LIBINPUT_DEVICE_GROUP=3/46a/11/111:usb-0000:00:14.0-1
MAJOR=13
MINOR=81
SUBSYSTEM=input
USEC_INITIALIZED=31155231
run: '/usr/local/bin/cherry.sh'
```

When the keyboard is plugged in, `/dev/cherrysymlink` is created. Also the debugging output says in the last line that the script `/usr/local/bin/cherry.sh` did indeed run.

The problem is, the script doesn't get actually executed.

`cherry_keyboard.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

xset r rate 150 60
```

It should change the autorepeat of the keyboard keys but it stays the same.

I've also tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

slock
```

Nothing happens. When I execute the scripts manually in the shell they both work. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

After modifying my script like this I am able to pipe the `echo` output into `dzen2` so it pops up on the screen:

```
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/*user*/.Xauthority

echo 'test' > /home/*user*/.udev_rule_scripts/test
echo 'test' | dzen2 -p 4
xset r rate 150 60
slock
```

So far, the first two `echo`-lines work. The `xset` and `slock` commands still don't work.

**EDIT2:**

After some reading I am pretty certain it has something to do with DBUS and the environment variable "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS". Also, when I run printenv as user, there is `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus` set. When I run printenv as root this variable is not set.

Therefore I made another modification to my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/*user*/.Xauthority
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus

echo 'test' > /home/*user*/.udev_rule_scripts/test
echo 'test' | dzen2 -p 4
xset r rate 150 60
slock
```

Unfortunately, it still doesn't work.

**EDIT3:**

After Gilles' suggestion I added a line to the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec >>/home/*user*/.udev_rule_scripts/test.log 2>&1; echo; date

export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/*user*/.Xauthority

echo 'test' | dzen2 -p 4

xset r rate 150 60
slock
```

which produces the following error message in `test.log`

```
Tue Feb 23 10:14:17 UTC 2016
/home/*user*/.udev_rule_scripts/cherry_keyboard: line 11:   858 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) slock
```

which (kind of) explains why `slock` fails to execute.
Sadly, there's nothing about `xset`.

**EDIT4:**

This time, I combined Gilles' and ojs' suggestions. Now the error messages are more interesting:

`cherry_keyboard.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec >>/home/*user*/.udev_rule_scripts/test.log 2>&1; echo; date

export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/*user*/.Xauthority

echo 'test' | dzen2 -p 4

su *user* -c "DISPLAY=:0 xset r rate 150 60"
su *user* -c "DISPLAY=:0 slock"
```

`test.log:`

```
Tue Feb 23 10:37:22 UTC 2016
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 43 requests (37 known processed) with 0 events remaining.

Tue Feb 23 10:38:37 UTC 2016
dzen: cannot open display
xset:  unable to open display ":0"
slock: cannot open display

Tue Feb 23 10:40:54 UTC 2016
```

Now here's the thing: When I plugin my keyboard, `dzen2` pops up on the screen, then the screen goes black. But not because of `slock`, it kind of crashes and when I type on the keyboard the screen stays black (which it shouldn't when slock was behind it). Other applications like `moc` are still running.

And now the strange part:

When I press the power button on my laptop to restart the system (which is the only option in this situation I think), before shutdown, the black screen disappears for half a second and instead a red screen appears (the red screen of slock when you type in a wrong password). So slock IS actually running. But why does the error message state that both `dzen` and `slock` "cannot open display", while they're in fact both running? And why does the screen crash? And in which way does `xset`'s error message differ?

An alternative `cherry_keyboard.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec >>/home/*user*/.udev_rule_scripts/test.log 2>&1; echo; date

export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/*user*/.Xauthority

echo 'test' | dzen2 -p 4

su *user* -c "DISPLAY=:0 xset r rate 150 60"
#su *user* -c "DISPLAY=:0 slock"
```

`test.log`:

```
Tue Feb 23 10:43:36 UTC 2016
```

So this time there are no error messages at all.

But, in both versions `xset` does not modify the autorepeat...

Comment: It could be that the script gets executed but by some reason the changes don't get applied. Try a simpler script, like `echo "hello" > /tmp/test` and see if the `/tmp/test` file exists and contains the word hello.

Comment: It could be that `PATH` is insufficient when executed via `udev`.

Comment: @ojs: That actually worked. But how come 'echo' works but other commands don't?

Comment: `udev` always runs scripts as `root`. Might it be that you need a simple `sudo -u userXYZ` for the `xset` settings? Also I had a problem recently with the `export DISLPAY=:0` part in a `udev` script (for `xmessage`s) and had to put it before every command (i.e. `DISPLAY=:0 sudo -u me xmessage hello`)

Comment: @Fiximan: Nope, `DISPLAY=:0 sudo -u user xset r rate 150 60` didn't work.

Comment: Try rather `su - arthur -c "DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/xset r rate 150 60"`, think that has a bigger chance of succeeding. Given that your username is arthur.

Comment: @ojs: unfortunately, still nothing.

Comment: Try `su - arthur -c "DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/xset r rate 150 60 2> /tmp/error"` and see if there is anything in that file, it catches any errors that the xset command produces.

Comment: @ojs: Just tried it, nothing. I think the xset command isn't executed at all because some xorg or dbus stuff. It's just strange that dzen2 works with the exported DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY variables and xset and slock don't.

Comment: Define “doesn't work” (beyond “doesn't have the effect I want”). What error messages do they produce? No, xset doesn't use D-Bus.

Answer (score 2):

For a start, your matching directives are seriously wrong: a better rule should match just on the SUBSYSTEM and USB VID and PID.

Anyway, you cannot just have root run commands which are supposed to control your active X session. If you really have to do that then you must at the very least import $DISPLAY and $XAUTHORITY, but the correct solution is to use the native tools of your desktop environment to run these commands when appropriate.

Comment: What's wrong with them? The thing is, I can run the commands from the shell as root or as user, it works both ways. I thought, since udev is running as root it should work, too. I try to keep my os as lightweight as possible, that's why I don't have a desktop environment, just Xorg and XMonad. Can you explain what do you mean by importing $DISPLAY and $XAUTHORITY?

Comment: @Arthur what I think Marco is talking about is that Linux is a server/client environment and when a udev rule runs a script, then it is not run from within the Xsession but just a random process from the server that does not know about Xsessions or what X is running (you can have multiple Xsession running on the same server for instance, so a script run by udev has no idea what Xsession to apply the `xset` command to). This is not a trivial task what you are trying to do and I don't have a solution to it unfortunately.

Comment: For example, if you go to a text terminal (tty1 for example, you can get there by pressing ctrl-alt-F1) and log in there and issue `xset q` then you will get an error saying that xset can't connect to terminal. If you do the same in an xterm then you will get lots of output. The same thing is happening to your script, it doesn't get any connection to a X server terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Scripts executed from udev run in an almost empty environment. They aren't attached to any particular session or terminal.

The first thing you need to do is read the error messages. Add `exec >>/var/log/my-udev-script.log 2>&1; echo; date` at the beginning of your script just below the `#!` line and have a look at `/var/log/my-udev-script.log` after the script has been triggered.

The `xset` command is an [X Window System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System#Software_architecture) client, so it needs to talk to an X server. It knows which X server to talk to (there could be many) from the value of the `DISPLAY` environment variable. If `DISPLAY` is not set, `xset` can't talk to any X server, so all it does is print an error message and exit.

To figure out how to set `DISPLAY`, and `XAUTHORITY` if necessary, see [Can I launch a graphical program on another user's desktop as root?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/can-i-launch-a-graphical-program-on-another-users-desktop-as-root/1600#1600) and [Open a window on a remote X display (why "Cannot open display")?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display/10126#1012) Note that it may be difficult to figure out what to do if there are multiple X servers.

Neither xset nor slock needs or cares about D-Bus. If you really need D-Bus, [How to start dbus with a fixed address?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114937/how-to-start-dbus-with-a-fixed-address) is the easiest way to go.

Comment: In one of your linked questions you say on some systems one must find the actual cookie file of XAuthority. Using `htop` I located it `/tmp/serverauth.cQuJ7XOujR`. Since `export XAUTHORITY=/home/*user*/Xauthority` is not working, is there a way how I can tell the script to look for the actual cookie file in `/tmp`?

Comment: @Arthur You tell the script where to look for the cookie file by setting `XAUTHORITY`. Take care that the location depends on whether a user is logged in (and if a user is just logging in it could change during the execution of the script).